# How to Tweak CSS script to make action appear in middle of Article

Tags: joomla-3.4

I have added the following code to my article:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="contents">
       <img src="image here">
    </div>
    <div id="gradient">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following code to my css

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    padding:50px;
    margin:50px;
}
#contents {
    background:white;
}
#gradient {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
    height:300px;
    background: none;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(80%,rgba(255,255,255,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Everything works fine, however can someone show me how to make the fade appear in the middle of the article? At the moment, the fades out at the end of the article.

Cheers

Carlton

Comment: Just a side note, `startColorstr='#00ffffff'` is incorrect. The colour hex you've defined has 8 characters, instead of 6

Comment: @Lodder That's because it is ARGB not RGB

Comment: FYI, since this really has nothing to do with joomla, should really be on SO

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the `80%` to `50%`.

```
#gradient {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
    height:300px;
    background: none;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Comment: Can someone show me how add some text to the fade section

Comment: Just include it in whatever div you apply the style to.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean? I haven't applied anything to my styles. I'm pretty much a novice to all this coding. I'm just copying coding from the internet and seeing if it works. So far it has worked. The only thing left is to add text to the faded area as I explained. The only file I have applied the code to is the articles and the template.css.

Comment: Yes you have, The `#gradient` in the css corresponds to the element with the matching id such as your `<div id="gradient">`

Comment: do you mean this <div id="container">
 <div id="contents"><img src="images/WAN650/exercise1/586-1200.jpg" alt="586 1200" /><img src="images/WAN650/exercise1/587-1200.jpg" alt="587 1200" />
 </div>
 <div id="gradient">
  <p style="line-height: 22.4px; text-align: center;"><span class="componentheading" style="font-size: 18pt; color: #ff9900;">We're Very Sorry, Full Content Access is For Members Only - </span>
  </p>
  <p style="line-height: 22.4px; text-align: center;"><span class="componentheading" style="font-size: 18pt; color: #ff9900;"><a href="index.php/ed-serv/settings-2"

Comment: I don't want to get in trouble by the administrators of this site by being considered as lazy, but can you give me an example?

Comment: Per your example `<div id="gradient">` already uses the gradient css.... That's what the `#gradient` in the css does, it targets the element with that id... Im really not sure how to explain it any simpler than that.

Comment: Hi @wobble, referring back to your suggestion where you mentioned to just change 80% to 50%, that actually didn't work. I even went as far as to change it to 0% and the fade action still didn't start from the middle of the page. :-(

Comment: It will start at whatever percentage of that ELEMENT. If you want the fade to happen at a certain percentage of the whole page you need to target the page element in your CSS, not just a div within it.

Comment: It works just fine; https://jsfiddle.net/ns5z7t8j/ if it is not working as expected then you have left somthing out in your post as what you were trying to acheive.